# Is GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) id a Unique id for android application?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I am using a mobile (Fly F45Q) and i got daily a new GCM id for my android application. this is not happen in other mobile Like (Samsung core/samsung at&t ) etc.i don't understand what is happening with this mobile.

can anyone please suggest to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

As google stated the registration ids are invalidated on the version change of application, also there is a possibility that the registration id gets changed on reinstall of the app. Not sure why its happening on this particular device. Is this change of registration id, only for your application or every application ?

Comment: Acutally its happen only in my device.